# 502 Bad Gateway on api.soundcloud.com /playlists HTTP API request

Tags: soundcloud

Simply souncloud servers responds with 502 Bad Gateway error on a **/playlists** call to API with *client_id* and *user_id* parameters. Issue regards a specific user, so maybe something it's messed up on server or on profile.. but how can I resolve?! There's no recovery procedure or similar to try things works again?

Comment: Well what does your code look like? It sounds like you need to resolve the client_id to get the playlist id.

Comment: Using my client_id I'm able to receive _/user_ response and also _/playlists_ response for other users.. only my specific one user make api responds with 502 error... I tried with official api wrapper, direct curl, direct http link, other client_id also.. some result.. :(

Comment: Well you could show us your code or at least the playlist name so other people can verify the same result.

Comment: https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists?client_id=a99587dd69ab6d0c88b3c31c9bdf31b8&user_id=radio-pnr

Comment: Playlist 'radio-pnr' comes up not found.

Comment: If you mean user 'radio-pnr' the call would be http://api.soundcloud.com/users/radio-pnr/tracks.json?client_id=

Comment: I need to retrieve the list of playlists by single user radio-pnr:
 **playlists?client_id=a99587dd69ab6d0c88b3c31c9bdf31b8&user_id=radio-pnr** not the tracks of a single playlist or a single user.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists

Comment: Ah. Now that we know what you're trying to do, I can verify your call above as well as the call http://api.soundcloud.com/users/radio-pnr/playlists?client_id=a99587dd69ab6d0c88b3c31c9bdf31b8 gives either a 502 Bad Gateway or a 504 Gateway Timeout response. This seems to be a SoundCloud server issue and you should report this to them asap. Another person with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078410/502-error-when-searching-on-soundcloud-playlists

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue on calls to /me/playlists.  Would love to hear from SoundCloud support about how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and believe I have found the root cause.  After trying the playlists query in browser & curl I was able to get the valid data response (JSON).
Turns out Soundcloud includes all the tracks information of each playlist!  I have the max (500) tracks in some playlists so the response payload size must be the issue.  It must also be why we get an occasional timeout response.
I will see what I can do about limiting the data size in the response and may try other libraries (I'm using soundcloud-ruby.)