# BatchRequest gives com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: java, http, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am performing a batch request to add users to groups on a org google apps domain. This worked fine for a batch with 400 such user-group addition pairs. But when I performed a batch execution for 500 , it gave a `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 502 Bad Gateway`

This is the code snippet for queuing and batch execution :

```
service.members().insert(grpEmail, to_b_added).queue(batch, callback)
//The above step is performed for all user-group pairs.
batch.execute();
```

[NOTE : I have increased the readTimeOut for the HTTPRequestInitilaizer, so that won't be an issue.]

This seems to be an issue on the google server, and I receive the error around 3-4 minutes after I have sent the batch request for execution.

Comment: Please check a similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763403/google-java-api-error-com-google-gdata-util-serviceexception-bad-gateway-du